# Sonarqube code coverage with OpenCover

Tags: c#, unit-testing, code-coverage, sonarqube

I'm currently using SonarQube 4.4 (latest) and I am trying to get a code coverage report for my c# project to appear. 
I have the Unit Test Success showing but the Code Coverage simply shows as " - " [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXaV6.png):

Here is what I am doing: I am following the sonarqube example page: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/csharp

I am running OpenCover and VSTest and configuring SonarQube to find the report.xml path under the CodeCoverage Configuration tab as well as configuring the Unit Test result paths.

From my understanding SonarQube no longer support Gallio, am I missing something?

Answer (score -2):

Indeed, the C# plugin does not support Gallio anymore. But the latest versions support importing test result reports generated by tools like OpenCover.

Please read the ["Code Coverage" documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/C%23+Plugin) to know how to do this.

Comment: Hi Fabrice, thanks so much for the reply, I am following the documentation, and I have set the reportPaths with my .trx file, but the code coverage still shows as "-", any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: IIRC, ".trx" files are not coverage files generated by OpenCover but test execution reports generated by VS.

Comment: Ah, you are right, sorry about that - I meant to say I am setting the opencover.reportpaths to point to my results.xml

Comment: Hummm, the most probable issue is that the OpenCover report has been generated when your project was built in a different folder than the one in which the SonarQube analysis is run.

Comment: So, I'm actually generating the report manually and (just for now) I have the file on my Desktop and am directly pointing to that file for the configuration

Comment: OK, would be best to send an email to the user mailing list, we're not going to be able to sort that out here.

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarQubeTeam how would I fix the issue where the OpenCover report has been generated in a different folder? What solution property, is that sonar.projectBaseDir ?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not supported yet.

Comment: FYI @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam bad link http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/C%23+Plugin